# Prompt user until correct type of input is entered

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
while (goodInput=false)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("How long is the word you would like to guess?");
                wordSize=scan.nextInt();
                while(wordSize>word.longestWord())
                {
                    System.out.println("There are no words that big! Please enter another number");
                    wordSize=scan.nextInt();
                }
                goodInput=true;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ime)
            {
                System.out.println("Thats not a number! Try again");
            }

        }
```

I am trying to prompt a user for a number but i cant get it to run correctly. I want it to keep running until the correct input is entered.

Comment: "I can't get it to run correctly" is **not** a real question.

Comment: Thanks thats true Mark. What is happening is it catches the error and then proceeds to the next lines after this segment. I think what Nambari said is what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is:

```
while (goodInput=false)
```

Assigns `false` to `goodInput` which becomes `while(false)` that leads to loop being not executed at all

change it to

```
while (!goodInput)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting recursion now but that may be a different problem.

Comment: @aaronbobaron: I would suggest debug (or) System.out first and  see which values leading to recursion. If still issue exists, post new question.

Comment: 27 more seconds, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The condition in `while` loop needs to be

```
 while(goodinput == false)
```

What you are doing is assign `false` to goodinput that results in final result as `false`. See the output of following statement,

```
boolean a;
System.out.println((a = false));
```

You need a [equality operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
while (goodInput=false)
```

Is assigning `false` to `goodInput`, you have to use `==` operator tocheck if `goodInput` is `false`

```
while (goodInput==false)
```

Or just

```
while (!goodInput) would suffice
```

here is the refrence to [**Equality Operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) in java

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
while (goodInput == false)
```

or even better

```
while (!goodInput)
```

instead of

```
while (goodInput = false)
```

The first one compares the value of `goodInput` with `false`, the second one negates the value of `goodInput` and your version assigns `false` to `goodInput`